# Pygame runs when importing from another module

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, networking, pygame

CODE THAT I AM RUNNING: Module Server

```
import socket
from _thread import *
from plyer import Player.  <--- Module that is causing the problem 
import json


class GameServer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Server = '127.0.0.1'
        self.Port = 52674
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.p = []  # Starting positions for player 1 and player 2
        self.PlayerId = 0
        self.Players = [Player(630, 375, 'R', 'Arsenal', position='ST'),
                    Player(630, 440, 'B', 'Arsenal', position='ST')]

    def Bind(self):
        # Connects the client to the server
        try:
            self.s.bind((self.Server, self.Port))
        except socket.error:
            print("Error")

        # Listens to maximum 2 players only
        self.s.listen(2)
        print("Waiting for a connection...")

    def ReturnSocket(self):
        return self.s

   def ThreadedClient(self, conn, curr_player):
        conn.send(json.dumps(self.Players[curr_player]))
        reply = ""
        while True:
            # Continuously runs when the client is connected
            try:
                data = json.loads(conn.recv(2048))
                self.Players[curr_player] = data

                if not data:
                    print("Player Left")
                    break
                else:
                    if curr_player == 1:
                        reply = self.Players[0]
                    else:
                        reply = self.Players[1]

                    print("Received: ", data)
                    print("Sending: ", reply)

                conn.sendall(json.dumps(reply))
            except:
                break

        print("Connection Lost")
        conn.close()


def main():
    GS = GameServer()
    GS.Bind()
    while True:
        s = GS.ReturnSocket()
        # Continuously looking for connections
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        print(addr, "has joined the game")

        # Function runs in the background
        start_new_thread(GS.ThreadedClient, (conn, GS.PlayerId))
        GS.PlayerId += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

CODE THAT I AM IMPORTING: Module plyer

```
import pygame
import sqlite3
import random


class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y, colour, team, position):
        self.window = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))

        # Connecting to the database
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect('/Users/kelanwestwood/Desktop/College Computer science project/Cvs '
                                'project/FifaStats.db')
        self.cur = self.conn.cursor()

        self.red = (255, 0, 0)
        self.blue = (0, 0, 255)
        self.Team = team
        self.Position = position

        self.PlayerName = self.PlayerFinder('Name')
        if self.PlayerName is None:
            if self.Position == 'LW':
                self.Position = 'LM'
            elif self.Position == 'RW':
                self.Position = 'RM'
            else:
                pass
        # Stats
        self.PlayerName = self.PlayerFinder('Name')
        self.Nationality = ""
        self.Pace = ""
        self.Shoot = ""
        self.Pass = ""
        self.Dribble = ""
        self.GKDive = ""
        self.Reflex = ""
        # Player
        self.x = x
       self.y = y
        self.width = 20
        self.height = 20
        self.Colour = colour
        self.rect = (self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height)
        # Barrier
        self.barrier = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 200, 200)
        # Player Controls
        self.HoldingBall = False
        self.DefendActive = False
        self.LockedPass = True

def DrawPlayerShape(self):
    # Colour option
    if self.Colour == 'R':
        self.Colour = self.red
    elif self.Colour == 'B':
        self.Colour = self.blue

    # print(co_ordinate)
    pygame.draw.rect(self.window, self.Colour, self.rect)
```

When I run the module Server, it keeps booting up Pygame and opening an empty black window. I have tried changing the import from import *, to from module import class, however the Pygame window keeps booting up. I do not even have anything running in the plyer module, to begin the Pygame window to open. Why does Pygame keep running when I import the plyer module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is NOT problem with `import`. You run `PyGame` in your server.

When you run server then you run `GameServer()`
and this runs `self.Players = [Player(...), ...]` in `GameServer.__init__()`
and this runs `pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))` in `Player.__init__()`.

And this displays `PyGame` window.

You would have to remove `pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 800))` to stop displaying window.

But later this can make problem with other functions, ie. `pygame.draw.rect` in `DrawPlayerShape`.

Frankly, server rather shouldn't use any `PyGame` functions. Only clients should use `PyGame`